# Print object properties using member function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am really confused with the task I received from the Jetbrains Academy.

There is a `calendar` object which has day, month and year properties. Somebody has created a `selectCurrentDay()` member function that sets the object's properties to the current day. There is no need to type the date manually anymore because we have the `selectCurrentDay()` function!

Initially, the calendar shows a random date. Implement the current date printing: select it and print the `day`, the `month` and the `year` split by a space.

Output example:

`21 12 2021`

What i did was:

```
val calendar = createCalendar()
calendar.selectCurrentDay()

print("{$calendar.day} ${calendar.month} ${calendar.year}")
```

However my answer is rejected. What do they want me to implement?

[image]

Comment: You forgot `{`: `${calendar.day}`

Comment: I edited the post once again,but it is still not the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print("${calendar.day} ${calendar.month} ${calendar.year}")
```